# Strange values in a recursion method in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, precision, trigonometry

As an exercise, One of our student in apprenticeship is supposed to implement a recursive Sine function. (Using the generalized continued fraction)
I tried to help him, having done a fair share of coding in comparison, and am now stuck with a problem I don't understand.

I have a function that works.
What I don't understand is why my first three or four attempt failed.
I tried to debug this thing step-by-step but I can't pinpoint my error. I really would like to know what I'm missing.

Beware, for the code is not as beautiful as it could be. It's a quick and dirty proof of concept I wrote (many times) in 5 minutes.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
// number = the angle in radian

static double sinus(double number, double exp = 1, bool mustAdd = false, double precision = 0.000001)
{
    if (number < 0) throw new ArgumentException("sinus");
    if (number == 0) return 0;
    double result = ((Math.Pow(number, exp)) / factorial(exp));
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    if (result > precision)
    {
        if (mustAdd)
            return result += sinus(number, exp + 2, !mustAdd);
        else
            return result -= sinus(number, exp + 2, !mustAdd);
    }
    else
        return result;
}
```

I'm printing every iteration with the intermediate values, in order to verify that everything is working accordingly. The values are correct.

Here's the working code I came up with (Yes it's dirty too):

```
static double Altersinus(double number, double exp = 1, bool mustAdd = true, double precision = 0.000001, double result = 0)
{
    if (number < 0) throw new ArgumentException("altersinus");
    if (number == 0) return 0;

    double tmp = ((Math.Pow(number, exp)) / factorial(exp));
    Console.WriteLine(tmp);

    if (tmp > precision)
    {
        if (mustAdd)
            result += tmp;
        else
            result -= tmp;
        result = Altersinus(number, exp + 2, !mustAdd, precision, result);

    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm also writing the intermediate values, and they are exactly the same as the function that doesn't work.

Again, I'm really not searching for a solution, there is no rush. I'm merely trying to understand why it's not working. I would like to know what's technically different between my two methods.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

**EDIT**

I tried both function with the value 3.14159265358979 (roughly 180 degree)

Both function are printing theses intermediate values :

```
3.14159265358979
5.16771278004997
2.55016403987735
0.599264529320792
0.0821458866111282
0.00737043094571435
0.000466302805767612
2.19153534478302E-05
7.95205400147551E-07
```

The method that doesn't works returns -3.90268777359824 as a result, which is completely false.

The one that does works returns -7.72785889430639E-07. Which roughly corresponds to a zero.

Comment: what goes wrong? You get the wrong answer? What inputs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've edited the question to include these elements

Comment: Don't shoot yourself in the foot, avoid recursion, here's a good tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and TL;DR use a queue or a stack then enjoy debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I generally avoid it where I can. It's much easier to code. Here, the problem is that I didn't understant what I did wrong

Comment: Side note: If the first parameter was called `radianAngle` instead, you wouldn't need that comment. Don't give parameters *generic* names (taken to the "logical" extreme, you first method's parameters should have been named `number1, number2, trueFalse, number3` and had you explain all of them in the comments!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Let's replace the calculus by 'nx' where x is the exposant and n the number.

In the function that does work, I am effectively this:

```
Sine(n)=n1/1! - n3/3! + n5/5! - nx/x!...
```

But the one that doesn't work is slightly different. It's doing something else:

```
Sine(n)=n1/1! - (n3/3! + (n5/5! - (nx/x!...)))
```

The key here are the parenthesis.
It's affecting the calculus big time, because of the substraction.

If there was only addition it would not have caused any problem.